# how to add values in an array from last value to first

Tags: java, arrays

How can I add the values in the arrNumbers that exceed 6 to add to a new array starting from the last value and ending at the first.

This is what I have written, but does not produce the right output.

```
    int[] arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2 };
    int[] newArrNumbers = new int[6];

    for(int i  = 0; i < arrNumbers.length ; i++){
        newArrNumbers[i % 6] += arrNumbers[i];
    }
```

The actual output:

```
newArrNumbers = [2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, I want the output to ADD to the LAST VALUE in the arrNumbers, going from right to left, not left to right. So result should be:

```
newArrNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7]
```

Comment: Given `n` as the length of an array, how would you, mathematically speaking, call the last, second-to-last, third-to-last etc... element of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
int[] arrNumbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2 };
int[] newArrNumbers = new int[6];

for(int i  = 0; i < arrNumbers.length ; i++){
    newArrNumbers[i < 6 ? i : (6 - (i % 6) - 1)] += arrNumbers[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArrNumbers));
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7]
```

Comment: Neat. You did his whole homework from him, that will for sure help him to learn programming!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks! I also hope so.

Comment: Sorry, that was sarcasm. People learn programming by programming themselves, not by having other people doing the heavy lifting for them. If you want to help, give them *hints* how to approach the problem themselves. Telling them the solution allows them to skip this assignment, and the more often they do that, the more likely they are to give up when things get too complicated and nobody else is willing to step up then.